# Error (-51), Extended Error 102 with Create Database User (Data Management Tools -> Geodatabase Management ->Create Database User)

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase

I'm trying to Create Database User so I can register my sde geodatabase data with ArcGIS Server. I can see in my Server Manager that the user does exist, but does not belong to any of the Windows AD groups associated with the ArcGIS server.  The database server is MS SQL 2014.

[image: Create Database User tool]

[image: Error message]

Comment: Unfortunately, you've scribbled out the important details and left off the version of ArcGIS in use..  I'd recommend you discuss this situation with Esri Tech Support.

Comment: Version of ArcGIS is 10.3.1.  I've only hidden our server name and the user name.

Comment: The user name is central to the  cause of the error, as is the configuration of the host on the domain, and probably the domain itself.  These do not lend themselves to an Internet solution.

Answer (score 2):

Have you created a Login for the user?  I was having this same issue where the user was created, however, I had not created a login.  I created the login and mapped it to the database the user was going to connect to.  Once I had done that, the tool ran correctly.